# How can I use persistant SMTP connection

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, persistent

I have a PHP application that uses CodeIgniter Email library class to send thousands of emails over SMTP protocol. The issue is, for each email sent, it uses a fresh connection with the SMTP server. How can I use a persistent connection in this case ?

For example, Suppose I send 1000 emails and then I do authentication once again and send 1000 more emails and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "bcc_batch_mode" in your email class.

See here for more info: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: I cant use bcc_batch_mode. Each email is unique and there are no BCC addresses to use. I just want to avoid SMTP authentication step for each and every email sent. It is OK to use authentication once in a while, but not for every email.

Comment: No one else can access docs on your localhost - I think this is the same page http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

since i didnt read your code, am going to post the one which they have put in the documentation ..

**$this->email->clear()**

Initializes all the email variables to an empty state. This function is intended for use if you run the email sending function in a loop, permitting the data to be reset between cycles.

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

and if this didnt work with you, i have another thing which is much more suitable and to be honest better than the builtin mail class, try to use the [Swift-mailler](http://s.zah.me/HusRRs) library which can solve most of your problem ..

Comment: I might give a try to Swift-mailer library at a later stage, but at the moment, I am looking for a solution with current CodeIgniter email library. I am not sure how could this function (email->clear) would help me to achieve persistent SMTP connection. My aim is to speed up email sending using SMTP. Something like SMTP Keep Alive feature with phpmailer library class.

Comment: Yes. I am already using that function in my email sending code. It does not help me in achieving persistent SMTP connection

Answer (score 0):

Simple like that:

Forget about CI's Email lib unless you'd be patient to change the core of the class... As a good alternative, use the PHPMailer class, put it in your CI/Application/libraries and with that you just need to set the property $SMTPKeepAlive to true, do what you want to do and after call SmtpClose();

I have a good implementation here using CI, I keep the SMTP servers in the database and all mailing stuffs are "ezfied" by a model I've wrote.

Rgds